# Android setting WebViewClient stops WebView from firing intents

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, webviewclient

I was playing with WebView and WebViewClient for a while, I found out that setting a WebViewClient to the WebView stops the intent fired while the user clicked on a link in the web page.

Problem is, I would like it all, in some cases I would like to manage the beautiful callbacks in the WebViewClient, such as onPageFinished, and sometimes let the webview handle the next page, and sometimes handle it myself(display other content) or to fired an intent to handle it.

Is this possible?